# ANT compilation error on updating selenium test result on TestLink

Tags: testlink

I am trying to run the TestNG tests using ANT. ANT executes it fine and creates an xslt report. When I add code in TestNg test to update Testlink ANT compilation fails with an error:

error: cannot find symbol  import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcConfig;
                                                    ^
   symbol:   class XmlRpcConfig
   location: package org.apache.xmlrpc
 1 error

BUILD Failed.

If I run TestNg.xml directly it updates everything in Testlink. Already imported xmlrpc.jar,xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar in my project LIB folder.

Snippet from Build.xml --

```
<property environment = "env"/>


<property name="project.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="${basedir}/Lib"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY_AU" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy" locale="en,GB"/>
  </tstamp>
```

```
<target name="setClassPath">
<path id="classpath_jars">
<pathelement path="${basedir}/" />
<fileset dir="${jar.dir}">
<include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>
<pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" /> 
</target>
```

```
<target name="TestNg" depends="setClassPath" >
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
</target>
```

Kindly help.